# duda de como hacer este ejercicio

Tags: ruby

Tengo un ejercicio de logica pero no he podido enteder como hacerlo

tengo un archivo txt con el formato pregunta respuesta y un salto de linea donde sigue ese mismo formato:

1-pregunta

respuesta

--salto de linea--

2-pregunta

respuesta

--salto de linea--

etc....

la idea es leer ese archivo txt y mostrar en consola la pregunta y luego que el usuario pueda responderla si queda bien continua con la siguiente pregunta si no vuelve a mostar la pregunta.

no se si me hice entender.

Comment: Por favor intenta alguna solución y agrega un __[mcve]__ que muestre el problema. Las preguntas que solicitan ideas, recomendaciones, opiniones o sugerencias deben ser cerradas. Las preguntas que solicitan soluciones sin mostrar esfuerzo personal, son cerradas igualmente. Por favor lee esta guía: _[ask]_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el formato del archivo de preguntas **siempre** será el mismo, puedes hacer algo así:

```
questions = File.readlines('preguntas.txt')

questions.each_slice(3) do |question, answer, _|
  loop do
    puts question
    given_answer = gets.chomp

    break if  given_answer == answer.strip
  end
end
```

- `readlines` lee el archivo y devuelve un arreglo donde cada elemento es una línea.
- `each_slice(3)` itera el arreglo en bloques de 3, dejando en la variable `question` la primer línea, en `answer` la segunda y en `_` la tercera (la cual ignoramos por ser una línea en blanco).
- El `loop` muestra siempre la misma pregunta hasta que el usuario pone la respuesta correcta.